# How to create a textfield with autocomplete function for the view?

Tags: 8, blocks

My Drupal 8 website is multilingual, and on one of the views I present a list of nodes (titles). On top of the page I need to implement a textfield with autocomplete function, where the user can start typing in the language, and then by choosing one the content on the page will be presented in chosen language.

I have started by creating a custom block:

```
public function build(){

$block = array(
  '#type' => 'textfield',
  '#title' => t('Choose language'),
  '#autocomplete_path' => '?????',
  '#cache' => array(
    'max-age' => 0,
  ),
);
return $block;
```

}

What should I write in '#autocomplete_path' => '?????' as the list of languages is not taxonomies. It is coming from Languages module. Could you please help me?

Answer (score 2):

I think no need to create block of view programmatically, You can do it with **Views Autocomplete Filters** module and **views** Module:
Try the following steps how to create view with language filter, using autocomplete:

1. Install [Views Autocomplete Filters](https://www.drupal.org/project/views_autocomplete_filters) Module.
2. Create View with `Fields` Display add the language field `The language of the content or translation.`
    and your additional fields:
   [image]
3. Add **Combine fields filter** 
   [image]

configure it like the following:
[image]
[image]

4. the result will be like:

[image]
[image]

Comment: Thanks a lot for your answer. It is exactly what I need. Just one more thing for me is that I have not-exposed filter criteria (Translation language = Content language selected for a page). And that's why I in the combined fields filter I can seacrh only for the current langauge of the page. Possibly I use wrong operator for the combined fields filter (Is equal to )?

Comment: It looks  that this solution could be good as a seacrh function, but not as a language switcher

Comment: @user91143 as you says this answer solve your question consider check it as accepted to help another users to find the correct answer if they have a similar problem.

Comment: It looked like a solution for me from the first look, but in fact it didn't solve my problem.